# Implementando Carousel de ejemplo de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy tratando de obtener el [carousel "with indicators"](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#with-indicators) que viene en la documentación de Bootstrap en [code pen](https://codepen.io/Baldan/pen/bmrmPg). Pero solo sé me ve la pantalla blanca con los nombres "first slide","second slide" y "third slide" pasando. Parece que la funcionalidad está bien, solo falla la apariencia, en el html he puesto un link al css como me indica la documentación. ¿Por qué no se me ve como en la documentación (con el fondo griss y la sensación que están pasando slides)?

Comment: ¿Tienes referenciado a bootstrap.min.js?

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez: si en la línea 12.

Comment: Ok, ya te han respondido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en que la ruta de las imágenes no la esta encontrando y las imágenes es lo que le da el alto y el ancho al carousel, ejemplo:

**Carousel copia fiel y exacta de Bootstrap:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=777&fg=555&text=First slide" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=666&fg=444&text=Second slide" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third slide" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Carousel de Bootstrap encontrando las imagenes:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg width%3D"800" height%3D"400" xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg" viewBox%3D"0 0 800 400" preserveAspectRatio%3D"none"%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle type%3D"text%2Fcss"%3E%23holder_1666e54fff8 text %7B fill%3A%23555%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt %7D %3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg id%3D"holder_1666e54fff8"%3E%3Crect width%3D"800" height%3D"400" fill%3D"%23777"%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext x%3D"285.9000015258789" y%3D"217.7"%3EFirst slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E' alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg width%3D"800" height%3D"400" xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg" viewBox%3D"0 0 800 400" preserveAspectRatio%3D"none"%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle type%3D"text%2Fcss"%3E%23holder_1666e54fffa text %7B fill%3A%23444%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt %7D %3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg id%3D"holder_1666e54fffa"%3E%3Crect width%3D"800" height%3D"400" fill%3D"%23666"%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext x%3D"247.2916717529297" y%3D"217.7"%3ESecond slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E' alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg width%3D"800" height%3D"400" xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg" viewBox%3D"0 0 800 400" preserveAspectRatio%3D"none"%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle type%3D"text%2Fcss"%3E%23holder_1666e54fffa text %7B fill%3A%23333%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C monospace%3Bfont-size%3A40pt %7D %3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg id%3D"holder_1666e54fffa"%3E%3Crect width%3D"800" height%3D"400" fill%3D"%23555"%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext x%3D"276.9749984741211" y%3D"217.7"%3EThird slide%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E' alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

EL fondo gris no es un fondo son imágenes. Ahora si quieres un carousel solo con DIVs puedes darles un alto y un ancho para emular el espacio de las imagenes así:

```css
.carousel-item{
  border:1px solid red;
  height:300px;
  line-height:300px;
  text-align:center;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(1){
  background-color:grey;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(2){
  background-color:orange;
}

.carousel-item:nth-child(3){
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">First slide</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Second slide</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Third slide</div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```